# Makefile Open externally managed shell and run command

Tags: makefile

I am trying to open and externally managed shell and trying to run some command in makefile. How can I do that?

For example, if I want to run the following sequence in my make file:

```
> python
> a = 6
> b = 5
> c = a + b
> print(c)
>exit()
```

This is a sample of externally managed shell that I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways, none of them super-simple.  Here's the most basic one:

```
runcommand:
        ( echo 'a = 6'; \
          echo 'b = 5'; \
          echo 'c = a + b'; \
          echo 'print(c)'; \
          echo 'exit()'; \
        ) | python
```

Basically, if you can write the command in a single shell command line, then you can transpose that command line into your makefile recipe.